# Navbar design with CSS and HTML like OLX.IN

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am trying to design a header similar to OLX.IN, i am trying but it not working as i need.

I am googled and tried to code myself but it not matching the design i am planning.

Design i am trying :

[Click to view the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybjtm.png)

My Code :

```css
.logo {
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.location {}

.location input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px #002f34 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.location .ico {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: inherit;
}


.search {}

.search input {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px #002f34 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.search .ico {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: inherit;
}

.sell {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: 3px #ffa500 solid;
  color: #002f34;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #a9a9a9;
}

.login {
  padding-right:10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.flex-1{
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-2{
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">
        <img src={require("../ui/logo.png")} />
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-2 pr-3">

            <li class="input-group input-group-lg location mr-4 flex-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pakistan" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="fas fa-search ico"></button>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="input-group input-group-lg search flex-2">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Mobile, Car ,laptop" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="fas fa-search ico"></button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <h6 class="mr-sm-2 login" >Login</h6>
            <button class="my-2 my-sm-0 fas fa-plus sell">&nbsp; SELL</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Can you help me with correct HTML and CSS tag or code to make a design which i want.

Comment: You want to make all menu items displayed from left to right horizontally?

Comment: @NickVu yes, same like olx.in

Comment: You may wanna check the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/)

Comment: @Ownagin i have design above from bootstrap itself. i am unable to figure out how i can archive the design i want. i keep trying but still no success.

Comment: You should use a updated version of bootstrap and pick a navbar from here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ and you can easily modify from that template.

Comment: @SaikatRoy I am trying now with latest bootstrap and trying hard to figure out. as i am not a experienced coder and designer. any code or tag help from you will be thankful.

Comment: Read about `display: flex`

Comment: It angers me that people load in all this bootstrap and jquery and crap just for a navbar. Use CSS flexbox/grid you don't need a bootstrap anymore